# How to display a school attendance register to show that a student was either present or not in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have an attendance module in a school ERP. There are 2 parts to it. In the first part, a teacher is able to mark attendances for each student using a drop-down with options: "present" and "absent". "present" has a value of 1, and "absent" has a value of 0.

[image: How a teacher marks attendance]

On save, the `teacher_id`, `class_id`, `term_id`, `session_id`, `student_id`, `is_present` (1 or 0) and the `date` from that day is saved in the attendances table. Here's the structure.

[image: attendances table structure]

N/B. the `teacher_id`, `class_id`, `term_id`, `session_id`, `student_id` fields are all foreign keys representing their tables respectively.

When it saves the attendance for the day succesfully, it redirects to a view-register view that should display the register showing a "tick" for students who were present and an "X" for students who were absent on a particular day like this.

[image: How attendance should display on a particular day]

Now, it is displaying under the first day instead of today 15th.

Also, I want to dispaly the marked attendances for the previous days under thier correct day.

Here's my code:

The method that renders the attendance register in the teacher's controller.

```php
public function viewAttendanceRegister()
{
    $maxDays = date('t');
    $currentDayOfMonth = date('j');
    $currentMonth = date('m');
    $currentYear = date('Y');

    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    $logged_in_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $logged_in_teacher_id = Teacher::where('user_id', $logged_in_user_id)->first()->id;

    $my_students = Student::where('teacher_id', $logged_in_teacher_id)->get();
    $student_ids = [];
    $class_id = [];
    $term_id = [];
    $session_id = [];

    foreach ($my_students as $student) {
        $student_ids[] = $student->id;
        $class_id[] = $student->class_id;
        $term_id[] = $student->term_id;
        $session_id[] = $student->session_id;
    }

    $check_attendance = DB::select(
        'SELECT DAY(:today) AS day, student_id, is_present FROM attendances WHERE class_id = :class_id AND teacher_id = :teacher_id AND term_id = :term_id AND date = :date',
        [
            'today' => $today,
            'class_id' => $class_id[0],
            'teacher_id' => $logged_in_teacher_id, 
            'term_id' => $term_id[0], 
            'date' => $today
        ]);
    $days = range(1, cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $currentMonth, $currentYear));

    return view(
        'teachers.view-register',
        compact('my_students', 'days', 'today', 'currentDayOfMonth', 'check_attendance')
    );
}
```

The method that saves the marked attendance.

```php
public function markAttendance(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

        $teacher_id = $request->input('teacher_id');
        $class_id = $request->input('class_id');
        $student_id = $request->input('student_id');
        $attendance = $request->input('attendance');
        $term_id = $request->input('term_id');
        $session_id = $request->input('session_id');
        $today = date("Y-m-d");

        $validation_count = Attendances::where('date', '=', $today)
            ->where('teacher_id', $teacher_id[0])
            ->where('class_id', $class_id[0])
            ->where('term_id', $term_id[0])
            ->where('session_id', $session_id[0])
            ->count();

        if ($validation_count > 0) {
            return redirect('teacher/attendance')
                ->with('attendance-error', 'You have already marked attendance for your class today.');
        }

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            array_map(function ($theTeacher, $theClass, $theStudents, $attendanceRecordForEachStudent, $theTerm, $theSession) {
                $attendances = new Attendances;

                $attendances->teacher_id = $theTeacher;
                $attendances->class_id = $theClass;
                $attendances->student_id = $theStudents;
                $attendances->is_present = $attendanceRecordForEachStudent;
                $attendances->term_id = $theTerm;
                $attendances->session_id = $theSession;

                $attendances->save();
            }, $teacher_id, $class_id, $student_id, $attendance, $term_id, $session_id);

            DB::commit();

            return redirect('teacher/viewRegister')
                ->with('success', 'Attendances Marked Successfully.');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            
            return redirect('teacher/view-class')
                ->with('error', 'We couldn\'t Mark Your Attendance, please contact the admin.');
        }
    }
}
```

My blade Attendance register.

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
        @section('content')
                <div class="dashboard-content-one">
                    <!-- Breadcubs Area Start Here -->
                    <div class="breadcrumbs-area">
                        <h3>Attendance</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/admin/admin-dashboard">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>Attendance</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Breadcubs Area End Here -->
                    <!-- Student Table Area Start Here -->
                    <div class="card height-auto">
                        <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: -1.5rem;">
                            <div class="heading-layout1">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3>Class attendance for today {{date("F j, Y.")}}</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"aria-expanded="false">...</a>
    
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/admit-student"><i class="fas fa-check text-dark-pastel-green"></i>#</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <form class="mg-b-20" method="GET" action="#">
                                <div class="row gutters-8">
                                    <div class="col-3-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by admission Id" class="form-control" name="admission">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4-xxxl col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Name" class="form-control" name="name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4-xxxl col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by Class" class="form-control" name="class">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-1-xxxl col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-12 form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="fw-btn-fill btn-gradient-yellow">SEARCH</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="table-responsive mb-3" >
                                <table class="table display data-table text-nowrap">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Photo</th>
                                            <th>Student</th>
                                            @foreach( $days as $day)
                                            <th>{{$day}}</th>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                            @foreach($my_students as $key => $my_student)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><img src="{{ asset('img/figure/student2.png')}}" alt="student" class="parent_photo"></td>
                                                    <td>{{$my_student->user->first_name . " " .$my_student->user->last_name}}</td>
                                                    @foreach($days as $day)
                                                        @if($day == $currentDayOfMonth)
                                                            @foreach($check_attendance as $attendance)
                                                                    @if($my_student->id == $attendance->student_id)
                                                                        @if($attendance->is_present == 1)
                                                                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success br-0"> &#10004; </a></td>
                                                                        @else
                                                                            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger br-0"> &#10006; </a></td>
                                                                        @endif 
                                                                    @endif
                                                            @endforeach
                                                        @endif
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
    
                                </table>
    
                            </div>
                            <hr class="mb-4 mt-3">
    
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    <!-- Student Table Area End Here -->
    @endsection
```

Please I would appreciate help in solving this problem.

I am available to answer any question or provide clarity regarding any aspect of this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this `SELECT DAY(:today) AS day` is not legal as you cannot use parameters for table or column names in prepared statements. But strangely, it does not throw an error when used but just returns the column name as a value

Comment: Actually its not that strange, its like a `SELECT "FRED".......`

Comment: Actually, I wasn't sure it would work as well. But it did.